# how to jump down n pages in vim

Tags: vim

If I want to jump `n` pages down in vim, how can I do it?

I don't want to calculate how many lines are there in a page and then jump that way. Is there any way to specify the number of pages in `ctrl-f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type the number of pages followed by PageDown or CTRL-F

eg.
`5<PageDown>` or `5<CTRL-F>`
= Move 5 pages down.